# word 2007 - word 2010 проблема с переносами

Tags: ms-word, совместимость, перенос-слов

Проблема: есть файл Word 2007, сохраненный даже и в doc и  в docx, отправляется в другую инстанцию, там его открывают в Word 2010 и видят другое кол-во страниц, страницы оканчиваются другими фрагментами, жесть, разврат и содомию. Проблема была решена ручками - открыл Word 2007, открыл Word 2010 и просматривал где косяки. А косяки вот где:
много таблиц, и следовательно переносов (в одном столбце), и из за того, что в Word 2007 переносы стоят одним образом, а в Word 2010 они оказываются абсолютно в другом месте, текст становится больше, все съезжает. И там и там в настройках страницы стоят автопереносы, приправленные мягкими переносами ctrl+дефис.

Вопрос: как закрепить переносы в исходном файле еще в Word 2007, сделав их "жесткими", чтобы такой оказии не происходило при открытии файла в Word 2010. 
Пакет обновления 3 для Word 2007 стоит, но он не решает эту проблему. Понимаю, что нужно пересаживать на более поздние MS Word, но пока, нельзя.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в разной настройке всякоразных границ и отступов. Проверьте.

Comment: Как вариант - есть функция - перенос страницы ( ---разрыв страницы---). Если сделать текст с таблицой таким, что б в конце раздела осталось несколько "резервных" (допустим 10) строк, то при увеличении размера текста эта "подушка" не допустит перенос на новую страницу. Желательно что б она была не больше чем 3/4 страницы и не меньше одной строки (подобрать). Т.е. нужно сделать так, что б документ был поделена на как можно больше разделов, от окончания каждого раздела до конца листа было небольшое к-во сток (которое зависит от возможных "колебаний" ).